# Why does this RNN in tensorflow not learn?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to train an RNN without using the RNN API in  tensorflow (2) in Python 3.7, so the code is very basic. Something is going really wrong, but I'm not sure what it is.

As a reference, I am using a dataset from this  [tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series) so I know what the error should roughly converge to. My RNN code is the following. What it is trying to do is use the previous 20 timesteps to predict the value of a series at the 21st timestep. I am training in batches of size 256.

While there is a decrease in loss over time, the ceiling is approximately 10x what it is if I follow the tutorial approach. Could it be some problem with the backpropagation through time?

```
state_size = 20  #dimensionality of the network
BATCH_SIZE = 256
#define recurrent weights and biases. W has 1 more dimension that the state 
#dimension as also processes the inputs
W = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(state_size+1, state_size), dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(np.zeros((1,state_size)), dtype=tf.float32)

#weights and biases for the output
W2 = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(state_size, 1),dtype=tf.float32)
b2 = tf.Variable(np.zeros((1,1)), dtype=tf.float32)


init_state = tf.Variable(np.random.normal(size=[BATCH_SIZE,state_size]),dtype='float32')
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-3)
losses = []
for epoch in range(20):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = 0

        for batch_idx in range(200):

            current_state = init_state

            batchx = x_train_uni[batch_idx*BATCH_SIZE:(batch_idx+1)*BATCH_SIZE].swapaxes(0,1)
            batchy = y_train_uni[batch_idx*BATCH_SIZE:(batch_idx+1)*BATCH_SIZE]
            #forward pass through the timesteps
            for x in batchx:
                inst = tf.concat([current_state,x],1)  #concatenate state and inputs for that timepoint
                current_state = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(inst, W) + b)  #
            #predict using the hidden state after the full forward pass
            pred = tf.matmul(current_state,W2) + b2

            loss += tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(batchy-pred))

    #get gradients with respect to parameters
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, [W,b,W2,b2])
    #apply gradients
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [W,b,W2,b2]))
    losses.append(loss)
    print(loss)
```

Comment: I think you need a buffer for decorrelate the training like in the tutorial.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried this and it doesn't resolve the issue

Comment: What pseudo code do you try to do?

Comment: I am trying to exactly reproduce the example from the link above:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series

Comment: You have no data input normalization: uni_data = uni_data.values

uni_train_mean = uni_data[:TRAIN_SPLIT].mean()
uni_train_std = uni_data[:TRAIN_SPLIT].std()

uni_data = (uni_data-uni_train_mean)/uni_train_std

Comment: But I would recommend to model your code to the tutorial in the beginning. Yours looks a lot different to here https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/structured_data/time_series.ipynb#scrollTo=0opH9xi5MtIk

Comment: I run the tutorial in the same notebook as I've run the code, all the preprocessing of the data is thus the same, including the input normalisation. I am aware it looks different, my question is why my version doesn't work. My goal wasn't to get a working version of the code, it was to implement it without using the RNN API. In the tutorial, they explicitly use the RNN api.